# interrupting edge in automata

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have the following automata in tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', node distance=3.6cm]
    \node[state] (1) {1};
    \node[state] (0) [above right of=1] {2};

    \path (0) edge[bend left] node {01} (1);


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would like to ``interrupt'' the edge where the label is present. I know it is possible to put the edge label beside the edge but this is not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way of doing this is to simply fill the node with white, which will cover the line:

```
\path (0) edge[bend left] node[fill=white] {01} (1);
```

(This doesn't actually create a gap in the line though, so it only works fine when the background actually is white.)

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', node distance=3.6cm]
    \node[state] (1) {1};
    \node[state] (0) [above right of=1] {2};

    \path (0) edge[bend left] node[fill=white] {01} (1);


  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```