# Interrupting edges for node text when the background is non-white

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In [interrupting edge in automata](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89083/interrupting-edge-in-automata), a simple way to interrupt an edge is given. It is simple and helpful, **iff** the background happens to be white (or at least a determined single color). Is there a way to achieve this effect when the background is a gradient/indeterminate?

Comment: If you 'draw' the path first with `draw=none` or just `\path` to place the node, you can then draw to and from the node. However, you might not get as smooth a curve as you'll have two curves in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a task for the [`reverse clip` trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12033/121799), see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495952) for a very similar application.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth', node distance=3.6cm]
   \shade[left color=red,right color=blue,middle color=magenta,shading angle=30]
   (-1,-1) rectangle (4,4);
    \node[state] (1) {1};
    \node[state] (0) [above right of=1] {2};

    \path (0) to[bend left]   node[midway](C) {01} (1);
    \clip (C.north east) rectangle (C.south west)
    (current bounding box.south west) -| (current bounding box.north east)
    -| cycle;
    \draw (0)  to[bend left] (1);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also make this a style for the node, see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448925). (Note, though, that the `use path` key there differs from the one recently added to Ti*k*Z.)Please see [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn) for an experimental library that contains style for this and similar styles.